# efficiently do weighted count the elements in the list

Tags: python, algorithm

So I have a python dict like:

```
 1:[ "red","blue","green"]
 2: ["blue","blue","red"]..
```

and so on.

and then i have another python dict:
score_dict = {

```
 pid: weight
 1: 2
 2: 20
 ...
}
```

So, what i want is.. 
in the first dict, count number of times two colors occur together.
and so on.
But that count be multiplied by their weight.

For example:

I want to find out how many times red an blue occured together in this list:

so for pid 1
   red and blue occurs once.

```
 so this is (1*2) # 2 comes from the score_dict as pid1 has a weight 2
```

and then for second

there are two blue, red pairs I can form

```
so this is (1*20) + (1*20)
```

So total score for blue and red occuring together is 2 + 20 + 20 = 42

Also, how do i extend it to 3 colors?

Like if i have to find out "red" "blue" and " green" occuring together?

Comment: I didn't get how you derived `so this is (2*20) + (2*20)`. There are two red and blue pairs so shouldn't it be 2*20?

Comment: @Abhijit: hi.. correct.. sorry my bad. :(

Comment: Can you just do product of count of all the colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

dict1 = {1:[ "red","blue","green"], 2: ["blue","blue","red"]}

weight = {1: 2, 2: 20}

score = 0

for k,v in dict1.iteritems():
    score += weight[k] * Counter(v)["red"] * Counter(v)["blue"]
```

Result:

```
>>> score
42
```

The last part of my code could be rewritten as generator comprehension:

```
score = sum(weight[k] * Counter(v)["red"] * Counter(v)["blue"] for k,v in dict1.iteritems())
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I fully understood but here's an idea:'

```
from collections import Counter

data = {
    1: ['red','blue','green'],
    2: ['blue','blue','red'],
}

weights = {
    1: 2,
    2: 20,
}

for k, v in data.items():
    score = sum([c * weights[k] for c in Counter(v).values()])
    print "so this is: %s val = %d" % (k, score)
```